# Issue while extending AbstractAuditingEntity in jhipster application

Tags: jhipster

While creating an entity, i wanted created date and modified date fields to be added, so i extended AbstractAuditingEntity and i modified my liquibase like the below format.

Liquibase:

```
**<column name="created_date" type="timestamp" defaultValueDate="${now}"> 

  <constraints nullable="false"/> </column>

  <column name="last_modified_date" type="timestamp"/>

  <dropDefaultValue tableName="load_provider" columnName="created_date" 
  columnDataType="datetime"/>**
```

If I update the fields of an entity, along with the modified date field the created date is also getting changed to the modified date.

Comment: Have you considered using this module? https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit

Comment: No i just extends my entity with AbstractAuditingEntity now it is working fine